# I have unlabelled data and I want to make it into labelled into three category 1.Refilling 2. theft 3. sloshing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

```
timestamp               vehicle_speed       fuel_in_lit
2022-01-01 00:00:03       0                    61
2022-01-01 00:00:23       2                    60 
2022-01-01 00:00:33       0                    59 
2022-01-01 00:00:43       0                    58 
2022-01-01 00:00:53       0                     56
```

- if vehicle speed is zero and fuel tank level increasing then it's refilling
- if speed is zero and fuel decreasing means it's theft means stolen the fuel
- other than this is sloshing

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to show the code you're having trouble with

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

IIUC, you can use a set of masks and [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
diff = df['fuel_in_lit'].diff()
# speed is 0
m1 = df['vehicle_speed'].eq(0)
# fuel is increasing
m2 = diff.gt(0)
# fuel is decreasing
m3 = diff.lt(0)

df['state'] = np.select([m1&m2, m1&m3], ['refilling', 'stolen fuel'], 'sloshing')
```

*NB. I probably would have used a additional condition where the speed is > 0 and the fuel is decreasing, but the above fits the description*

output:

```
             timestamp  vehicle_speed  fuel_in_lit        state
0  2022-01-01 00:00:03              0           61     sloshing
1  2022-01-01 00:00:23              2           60     sloshing
2  2022-01-01 00:00:33              0           59  stolen fuel
3  2022-01-01 00:00:43              0           58  stolen fuel
4  2022-01-01 00:00:53              0           56  stolen fuel
```